# Easiest way to redirect an event registration confirmation to another page

Tags: civievent, redirect

After event registration, on the confirmation page, we simply want a new window to open or for the page itself to redirect after 5 seconds to another page. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://civicrm.org/extensions/front-end-page-options

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I haven't used that extension in a while, but IIRC it's the correct answer.  Why not post it as an answer rather than comment?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact flow you need you may find this Fuzion [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/front-end-page-options) offers what you need as it provides fields eg on an Event where you can specify the page to redirect to after submission.

Note it has a dependency on another Extension