# Modify "Thank-you Screen" fields to support tokens?

Tags: civievent, tokens, registration, online-registration, participants

I would like to display some data attached to an event registrant on the Thank-you page. Is there a way to enable Token parsing on the Thank-you Title, Introductory Text, and Footer Text?

Example:

```
Hey there {contact.first_name}, thanks for registering for this event!
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite in the way you'd like, unfortunately.  In time, this will be possible with Form Builder, but not yet.

For now, you have a few options.  I won't go into details, but will answer follow-up questions if other Stack Exchange questions/online docs don't help.

First - the simplest solution *might* be to redirect to a different page of your choosing.  If you have another page that you can configure with their info (e.g. a Drupal View), use the [Front End Page Options](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/24749/12) extension.

The second-simplest answer is to modify the thank-you template.  This isn't ideal because your thank-you page will be stuck on the current version of CiviCRM unless you manually redo your changes on each upgrade.  I only recommend this because it takes the least tech knowledge (though still quite a bit!).

- Define a custom template directory at **Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs** and **Administer » System Settings » Directories**.
- In that folder, make the following folder hierarchy: `CRM/Event/Form/Registration`.
- Find that same folder relative to your CiviCRM root folder (in `modules` on Drupal/Backdrop, `plugins` on WP) and copy `ThankYou.tpl` to the equivalent location in your custom templates folder.
- You can now modify the (new) `.tpl` file to add text/tokens.  You'll see a bunch of tokens in the file, but these aren't the "normal" tokens, which aren't available here.  You can see all available tokens by adding the `{debug}` token to the page.

Note that if you're comfortable writing extensions and/or using the API and/or using Javascript, this is NOT the way to go, because of the maintainability issue.

The most "correct" way would be an extension with `hook_civicrm_buildForm` to modify the text on the page - though I'd probably just use the extension to load a line or two of jQuery to get the job done.

**EDIT** - I just looked at your StackOverflow history, and it seems you're a coder and know jQuery - great!  Go ahead and download [civix](https://github.com/totten/civix), which lets you create a new extension (`civix generate:module NewExtensionName`).  Then check out the [Resource Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/) to see how to add JS to a form using `hook_civicrm_buildForm`.  If you know PHP, you can also check out the [Region Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/region/) to see how to inject a bit of HTML into the middle of the page.  The `$form` object should contain the name of the registrant.